# tsql join 2 tables with duplicate records in the second table

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 tables.

**Table 1:**

```
Id     Name

1      John
2      Mike
3      Sam
```

**Table 2:**

```
Name   Data

John   Data1
John   Data1
John   Data1
Mike   Data2
Mike   Data2
Sam    Data3
```

If I write

```
select Table2.Name, Table2.Data 
from Table1 
inner join Table2 on Table1.Name= Table2.Name
```

I get all the duplicate data.

I would like to be able to retrieve something like:

```
John Data1
Mike Data2
Sam  Data3
```

Comment: Your data doesn't make enough sense. Why is `Data1` repeated in second table?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do that.

You can use `distinct` clause:

```
select distinct t2.Name, t2.Data 
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Name= t2.Name
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187831%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is link to MSDN.

You can use `group by` :

```
select t2.Name, t2.Data 
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Name= t2.Name
group by t2.Name, t2.Data
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) is link to MSDN.

I prefer second solution, because I always can add grouping functions.

**Note:**
In both queries I used aliases (`t1`,`t2`). It's more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME
     , DATA
  FROM Table2
 WHERE NAME IN (SELECT NAME
                  FROM Table1)
```

There are a few different options here...

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE for this and apply a `row_number()`

```
;with cte as
(
  select t1.name, t2.data,
    row_number() over(partition by t1.id order by t1.id) rn
  from table1 t1
  inner join table2 t2
    on t1.name = t2.name
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Or a non-CTE version:

```
select *
from 
(
  select t1.name, t2.data,
    row_number() over(partition by t1.id order by t1.id) rn
  from table1 t1
  inner join table2 t2
    on t1.name = t2.name
) x
where rn = 1
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5b10/5)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
select Table2.Name, Table2.Data, count(*) from Table1 
     inner join Table2 on Table1.Name= Table2.Name
     group by Table2.Name, Table2.Data;
```